# need help to modify my react code for protected routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My react codes are mostly based on the Core UI sample dashboard and I just got some idea for protected routes from here: https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/issues/113

After applying the authentication codes to my `app.js` it doesn't work well. I think that

`Route render = (props ...)` has be changed to `component={component_name}`.

Therefore I am trying to fix the original codes(routes) to UnauthenticatedRoute or AuthenticatedRoute., but I'm still stuck in fixing the thing.

I could use some advice on how to do this.

Here is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import './scss/style.scss';

/////codes for the protected routes

const isAuthenticated = () => {
  console.log("[[[[[ This is an Authentication Method]]]]]]")
  return false;
}

const UnauthenticatedRoute = ({ component, ...rest } ) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    !isAuthenticated()
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/' />
  )} />
);


const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component, ...rest }  ) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    isAuthenticated()
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
);

////// Up to here

const loading  = (
  <div className="pt-3 text-center">
    <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
  </div>
)
// Containers
const TheLayout  = React.lazy(() => import('./containers/TheLayout'));

// Pages
const Login  = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/login/Login'));
const Register  = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/register/Register'));
const Page404  = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/page404/Page404'));
const Page500  = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/page500/Page500'));

class App extends Component  {


  render() {
    return (
      //TODO
      // Original codes for Routes work well but, UnauthenticatedRoute doesn't
    
        <HashRouter>
            <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
              <Switch>
             
                <Route exact path="/register"  render={props => <Register {...props}/>} />
                <Route exact path="/404"  render={props => <Page404 {...props}/>} />
                <Route exact path="/500"  render={props => <Page500 {...props}/>} />
                <Route path="/"  render={props => <TheLayout {...props}/>} />
                <UnauthenticatedRoute exact path="/login" name="Login Page" component={Login} /> 
              </Switch>
            </React.Suspense>
        </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```